# A Safe Segmentation Fault?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, segmentation-fault

In my simple game, there is a thread that does the drawing to the screen. I made my program throw an exit signal as an exception when I press the ESC key. Whenever this exception is caught, the clean-up function is called and the program exits. This 'expected' segmentation fault occurs when the clean-up function is called while a drawing to the screen was not completed, and as a result the drawing thread is somewhat orphaned. My Ubuntu Linux OS seems to handle this safely and does not crash, although it tells me a segmentation fault. Do you think it is fine to leave it this way? If not, what kind of serious problems I may face? I'm just a little interested in what happens deep inside the system in such situations.

Comment: Heh? what do you mean by `handle this safely and does not crash, although it tells me a segmentation fault`?

Comment: Also, you may like to read about [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: There is another recent question about _recovering_ a SIGSEGV, which is impossible.

Comment: @iharob By any chance, do you have any answer to my first comment? I'm still confused.

Comment: @SouravGhosh What I meant by 'not crash' is that at least the system is still responsive to do my favours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, the main thread is freeing memory used by the drawing thread without any form of synchronization, i.e., the main thread may free that memory when it is being written by the drawing thread.

It's not safe, and you most definitely shouldn't be leaving it that way. The exit handlers on the main thread should either stop the drawing thread, or wait for it to complete, and only then free the memory.

As you describe it, your code has undefined behavior. Note that working as expected is a valid form of undefined behavior -- but it doesn't mean it will always work as expected. Anything can happen.

Answer (score 3):

That segmentation fault probably means that you are trying to access memory outside the process reserve set by the kernel.

You should try and fix the problem causing the segmentation fault, a tool very useful for memory analysis is [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) you can install it from your ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 1):

This does not sound like a good design, and in fact sounds very similar to the [Coding by exception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_by_exception) anti-pattern.  It would be better to have the thread post the event back to the main tread, and perform a 'join' to have a controlled shut-down.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to exit the program, you can just hide the gui and try to flag all the threads that are running to stop. Before call exit on the program check in a loop until all the threads have been stopped with a timeout of iterations. To avoid overloading the cpu put a sleep on this loop

Comment: Sleep in a loop is not really the best way of synchronization, since you have better mechanisms.

Comment: Not for sincronization, but if you only check if the threads have finished their work, you can use a loop in a low priority thread, so a sleep can be added here. As the question said the problem is not sicronization, but the way of closing the application. In order to close a multithreaded app you need to assure that all threads have finished working so that is what i suggest with flags

Comment: Well, waiting for some kind of event to happen in different thread/process is usually a synchronization problem. Active waiting (even with sleep) is not the best idea.